# How to determine the encoding of the string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I have a string received via the `gets.chomp` of the `TcpSocket` class. How can I determine the encoding of this string? Then I need to convert it to the Windows console encoding so I can print it. Is there any built-in way or third-party library to do it in Ruby?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- How can I determine the encoding of this string?

Use this method [`#encoding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-encoding)- *Returns the Encoding object that represents the encoding of obj.*

- Then I need to convert it to the Windows console encoding so I can print it...

Take look at the class [`Encoding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Encoding.html) to get the ideas, about how to convert to required encodings.